# Create a scaled image of a JComponent for minimap

Tags: java, jpanel

I've got a java swing application with a large JPanel as it's main container. I have smaller jPanels on it and this makes up a diagram. These diagrams can get large, so I'd like to implement a simple minimap thing. I'd have a colored rectangle around it, and a scaled down version of the main diagram. It would be read only. The user could then move the rectangle to quickly move around parts of the diagram.

Think [Age of Empires](http://www.gamershell.com/screenshots/2727/42579_full.jpg)

What is the best way to go about this? I'm fairly new to swing so really confused.

EDIT:

So I'm guessing I'll need to do something like I did for printing

```
// Create a clone of the graphics context.  This allows us to manipulate
            // the graphics context without begin worried about what effects
            // it might have once we're finished
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();


            // Create a new AffineTransformation
            AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();

            // Set the scaling
            at.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);

            // Apply the transformation
            g2.transform(at);

            // paint the component
            comp.paintAll(g2);

            // Dispose of the graphics context, freeing up memory and discarding
            // our changes
            g2.dispose();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are any number of ways to achieve this.  I would start with a scaled down image of the map area, one whose scale you know when compared to the "zoomed" view...

Based on the current coordinates of the user's "zoomed" view, you would need to scale these to the minimap scale and generate a rectangle on it's surface.

Start by taking a look at

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)
- [Reading/Loading images](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)

For some more ideas...